# ActionBar Sherlock , action bar tabs and fragments

Tags: android, tabs, fragment, actionbarsherlock

I want to create a single app for both mobile and tablet .I am using actiobBar sherlock library. I have a MainActivity which extends SherlockFragmentActivity. MainActivity has an actionbar which contains only tabs.
 Now , I want  to associate a fragment for each tab and this fragment should has two fragments(list fragment and detail fragment) . Please suggest me how to do this.

Comment: did you ever find out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is several methods, i'll only explain mine.

You can use any navigation, ViewPager, TabAdapter...
The idea is **adding a layer of fragments**.

For example you have your TabAdapter with a view pager :

```
    private ViewPager           _viewPager;
    private TabsAdapter         _tabsAdapter;

   _tabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, _viewPager);
   _tabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setCustomView(getTabIndicator(getString(R.string.tle_tab_home), R.drawable.ic_menu_home)), FragmentAccueil.class, null);
   _tabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setCustomView(getTabIndicator(getString(R.string.tle_tab_directory), R.drawable.tab_list_icon)), ContainerFragmentAnnuaire.class, null);
```

ContainerFragmentAnnuaire is a layout that contain fragments

for example for handset you ll create this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment class="com.example.android.ContainerFragmentAnnuaire"
              android:id="@+id/list_frag"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

for **tablet** you ll create this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/frags">
  <fragment class="com.example.android.ContainerFragmentAnnuaire"
            android:id="@+id/list_frag"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/titles_size"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
  <fragment class="com.example.android.ContainerFragmentDetail"
            android:id="@+id/details_frag"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

just add the layout in the good folder

res/layout/layout.xml for **handsets**

res/layout-large/layout.xml for **tablets**